# Adding numbers to lists in python

Tags: python

```
c = int(input('somenumber')) 
p = 0 
while p < c: 
    test = [1, 2] 
    test.append(p) 
    p = p + 1
```

I want to add numbers to a list but I do not want to use `sort` (since they are not an arithmetic progression; this is just a test example and I know sort can be used). The above code I tried to do something but the above code literally does nothing (what's wrong with it?

Comment: Note that you keep redefining the list *inside the loop*.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply , I'm trying to add certain numbers to the list which are not necessarily in an AP . like [1, 2, 3 , 4 ...] . In this example I want the out put to be [1, 2, and I have an algorithm that generates those number , I just want to put it in a list .

Comment: Yes, but the point stands - you need to initialise the list *outside the loop*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `test = [1, 2]` inside the loop is going to meant you only get 1,2 and the last `p` added to the list, you need to initialise the list outside the while loop:

```
c = int(input('somenumber')) 
p = 0 
test = [1, 2]  # outside loop
while p < c:     
    test.append(p)
    p += 1
print(test) # print test to see the contents when the loop finishes


In [1]: for i in range(3):
   ...:     test = []  # keeps resetting test to an empty list
   ...:     test.append(i)
   ...:     print(test,i)
   ...:     
([0], 0)
([1], 1)
([2], 2)

In [2]: test = [] # initialised outside the for loop so we get all elements appended

In [3]: for i in range(3):
   ...:     test.append(i)
   ...:     print(test,i)
   ...:     
([0], 0)
([0, 1], 1)
([0, 1, 2], 2)
```

Comment: Ya ! , I got my expected output </br>
But I don't get it , what's the difference between putting the list inside the loop and outside the loop ?

Comment: you keep making test to equal `[1,2]` on each iteration, put a `print test` inside the while loop in  your code to see.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are initializing the test list outside the loop.

Anyway starting from your specific example you can get the same result with fewer lines of code:

```
c = int(input('somenumber'))
p = 0
test = [1, 2]
test.extend(range(p, c))
print (test)
```

Comment: No need for the `x for x in...` it's redundant. `test.extend(range(p, c))` is fine

Comment: There's no list comprehension in your current answer.